# electron-forge package Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am trying to run the packaged electron app on my local Mac. But get an error message saying `Error: Cannot find module ...` I think the `node_module` is not installed.

I used `electron-forge package` to build the package.

Is there something wrong with my webpack config?

https://github.com/zhex900/mir-kiosk-electron/blob/master/electron-kiosk/webpack.main.config.js

```
#package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-iot": "^3.14.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.14.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.14.0",
    "aws-iot-device-sdk-v2": "^1.4.5",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "macaddress": "^0.5.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

[image]